# c++ videoplayer ffmpeg: get pixel data?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, video-processing

I want to get the pixel data of a frame. I found this (in original version as old code) and changed some things.

I have this code:

```
AVFormatContext *pFormatCtx;
pFormatCtx = avformat_alloc_context();
// Open file
if (int err = avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, file, NULL, 0) != 0)
{
    exit(2);
}
// Get infromation about streams
if (avformat_find_stream_info(pFormatCtx, NULL) < 0)
{
    exit(2);
}

// # video stream
int videoStreamIndex = -1;
AVCodecContext *pVideoCodecCtx;
AVCodec *pVideoCodec;
int res = 0;
int width = 0;
int height = 0;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < pFormatCtx->nb_streams; i++)
{
    if (pFormatCtx->streams[i]->codec->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO)
    {
        videoStreamIndex = i;
        pVideoCodecCtx = pFormatCtx->streams[i]->codec;
        // Find decoder
        pVideoCodec = avcodec_find_decoder(pVideoCodecCtx->codec_id);
        if (pVideoCodec)
        {
            // Open decoder
            res = !(avcodec_open2(pVideoCodecCtx, pVideoCodec, NULL) < 0);
            width = pVideoCodecCtx->coded_width;
            height = pVideoCodecCtx->coded_height;
        }
        break;
    }
}
// Frame width
width = pFormatCtx->streams[videoStreamIndex]->codec->width;
// Frame height
height = pFormatCtx->streams[videoStreamIndex]->codec->height;


AVPacket packet;
int got_picture_ptr;
AVPacket *avpkt;
AVFrame * pOutFrame;
pOutFrame = av_frame_alloc();
AVFrame * rgbOutFrame = av_frame_alloc();

if (!pOutFrame) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate video frame\n");
    exit(1);
}

while (av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, &packet) >= 0)
{
    if (packet.stream_index == videoStreamIndex) 
    {
        // Decode packeg to frame.
        int videoFrameBytes = avcodec_decode_video2(pVideoCodecCtx, pOutFrame,
            &got_picture_ptr, &packet);

        // Create context
        SwsContext* pImgConvertCtx = sws_getContext(pVideoCodecCtx->width,
            pVideoCodecCtx->height,
            pVideoCodecCtx->pix_fmt,
            pVideoCodecCtx->width, pVideoCodecCtx->height,
            AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P,
            SWS_BICUBIC, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        // Convert frame
        sws_scale(pImgConvertCtx, pOutFrame->data, pOutFrame->linesize,
            width, height, rgbOutFrame->data, rgbOutFrame->linesize);
    }

}
```

I know, that the code from `SwsContext` and `sws_scale` is wrong but I wonder, where can I find the pixel data of my frame... (and in which format it is stored).

Can someone help me here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pixel data is stored in *data* field.

According to the documentation:

> uint8_t* AVFrame::data[AV_NUM_DATA_POINTERS]
>
> pointer to the picture/channel planes.

Look [here](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.8/structAVFrame.html#a1d0f65014a8d1bf78cec8cbed2304992) for more information.

Generally speaking, your code is a bit misleading and rather buggy. I can point out some drawbacks:

1) You don't need to create new `SwsContext` on every incoming video packet. Just create it once before `while` cycle.

2) Next, you have an `rgbOutFrame`, but `SwsContext` is created for scaling into the `YUV420` pixel format. It looks strange.

3) Besides, `avcodec_decode_video2` is invoked, but you never check neither return value nor `got_picture_ptr` flag. Such practice is **really** error-prone.

And so on...

Hope it'll help you to improve your program and get necessary results.

Comment: thank you for your fast answer, but i still have some problems: what is a picture plane? and what should i do to get the pixel values?

Comment: i tried to use something like frame->data[0][i] for the value at position i, but it is a uint8_t (i thought of rgba). but when I use it like rgba only the alpha value has a value that is not zero... help please :/

Comment: @3DExtended Try to change `sws_getContext` to convert to `rgb`, not to `yuv420`

Comment: i did this and it does not change something :/ i used AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24 as desired outputformat

Comment: @3DExtended You can compare your whole program with this tutorial: http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/tutorial01.html. It should help to fix problems.

Comment: @3DExtended I'm glad to hear it!